# Python scipy fsolve works incorrectly

Tags: python, scipy, equation

I have equation:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

def wealth_evolution(price, wealth=10, rate=0.01, q=1, realEstate=0.1, prev_price=56):
    sum_wantedEstate = 100
    for delta in range(1,4):
        z = rate - ((price-prev_price) / (price + q / rate))
        k = delta * np.divide(1.0, float(np.maximum(0.0, z)))
        wantedEstate = (wealth / (price + q / rate)) * np.minimum(k, 1) - realEstate
        sum_wantedEstate += wantedEstate
    return sum_wantedEstate
```

So I find the solution of this equation:

```
sol = optimize.fsolve(wealth_evolution, 200)
```

But if I substituted `sol` into equation I wouldn't get `0` (`welth_evolution(sol)`). Why it happens? `fsolve` finds the roots of `f(x)=0`.

UPD:
The `full_output` gives:

```
(array([ 2585200.]), {'qtf': array([-99.70002298]), 'nfev': 14, 'fjac': array([[-1.]]), 'r': array([  3.45456519e-11]), 'fvec': array([ 99.7000116])}, 5, 'The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the \n  improvement from the last ten iterations.')
```

Comment: you may want to show a [mcve]

Comment: It would also be helpful if you posted the debugging output produced by `full_info=True`.

Comment: @cel  Actually, it is pretty close as is.  Run the code, and check the result with `wealth_evolution(sol)`.

Comment: Roma, take @ali_m's advice (except the argument to use is `full_output=True`).  In particular, look at `ier` and the error message.  (Also figure out why you are getting a warning about division by zero.)  When `full_output=True` is used, the function returns `ier=5`, which is an error condition.  What I don't understand is why the function doesn't raise an exception.

Comment: Actually, the first time you run it without `full_output=True`, the code generates a RuntimeWarning about not making good progress.  That's a sign that you should rerun the code with `full_output=True`.  (It is a bit annoying that if you run it again with the same initial guess, you don't get that warning.  This is an example where python's default warning behavior can be deceptive, and scipy should probably override it and always generate the warning.)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser And what I have to do for correct solving the equation? `full_output=True` gives `array([-99.70002298]), 'nfev': 14, 'fjac': array([[-1.]]), 'r': array([  3.45456519e-11]), 'fvec': array([ 99.7000116])}, 5, 'The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the \n  improvement from the last ten iterations.')`

Comment: See @thomas's answer.  Are you sure your function *has* a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried plotting your function?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
small = 1e-30
def wealth_evolution(price, wealth=10, rate=0.01, q=1, realEstate=0.1, prev_price=56):
    sum_wantedEstate = 100
    for delta in range(1,4):
        z = rate - ((price-prev_price) / (price + q / rate))
        k = delta * np.divide(1.0, float(np.maximum(small, z)))
        wantedEstate = (wealth / (price + q / rate)) * np.minimum(k, 1) - realEstate
        sum_wantedEstate += wantedEstate
    return sum_wantedEstate




price_range = np.linspace(0,10000,10000)
we = [wealth_evolution(p) for p in price_range]

plt.plot(price_range,we)
plt.xlabel('price')
plt.ylabel('wealth_evolution(price)')
plt.show()
```

[image]

At least for the parameters you specify it does not have a root, which is what `fsolve` tries to find. If you want to minimize a function you can try `fmin`. For this function this will not help though, because it seems to just asymptotically decay to 99.7 or so. So *minimizing* it would lead to infinite *price*.

So either you have to live with this *or* come up with a different function to optimize *or* constrain your search range (in which case you don't have to search, because it will just be the maximum value...).

Comment: It always amazes me that folks take an nice, interactive tool like Python, and then expect it to magically find something they 'know' is there without checking (by plotting) that it actually is there. You should always plot your functions! This should give you very good information about which solver (or minimizer) to use, and good ideas about where to start the search. Compared to the days of Fortran programs running on cards (yes, I did this), it is so easy to do now.